# Gunicorn Error 14: source: not found NGINX

Tags: python, vue.js, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am working on a ecommerce project and it was working fine, until I deleted the old web-backend folder and uploaded a new one (I understand that this is not correct, I had problems with my Github directory for that folder and made lots of mistakes so I had to clean the whole thing.) For that project I used Django Rest Framework and Vue.js. I'm using supervisor to manage the gunicorn and run it on the background. I am using the exact same setting that another project that was built exactly the same that is working fine, but that one gives me errors when I try to test ./gunicorn_start bash script.

The error says that line 14 source ../venv/bin/activate not found. This is weird, because I am using the same configuration, structure, nginx settings, everything is the same as my other working project.

Does that have something to do with permissions? If not, what could be wrong? I can't understand, because my other project that has everything the same is working fine. Hope you will be able to help. Thank you!

This is my gunicorn_start script:

```js
#!/bin/sh

NAME='ecologic'
DJANGODIR=/webapps/ecologic/web-backend
SOCKFILE=/webapps/ecologic/venv/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=ecologic
GROUP=webapps
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=core.wsgi
TIMEOUT=120

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../venv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--timeout $TIMEOUT \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

```js
./gunicorn_start
./gunicorn_start: 14: source: not found
[2021-12-28 11:10:14 -0500] [730777] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
  wsgi_app: None
  bind: ['unix:/webapps/ecologic/venv/run/gunicorn.sock']
[2021-12-28 11:10:14 -0500] [730777] [WARNING] Worker with pid 730781 was terminated due to signal 15
[2021-12-28 11:10:14 -0500] [730777] [WARNING] Worker with pid 730782 was terminated due to signal 15
[2021-12-28 11:10:14 -0500] [730777] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-12-28 11:10:14 -0500] [730777] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: `source` is a bashism but your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` -- try `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or use the more portable `. file/to/source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem was the permissions. Solved it buy going back to the main folder and giving ownership to the user. In my case it was chown -R ecologic:webapps . (Don't forget about the dot at the end, this will give the user ownership over all of the folders in current directory).